# JSON.parse is outputting a string

Tags: javascript, json

What's going on here?

```
var data = '"[2743,1,1,1,1,1]"';
var flags = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(typeof flags);      // this outputs "string"
```

I was expecting `flags` to be an object or array, but it's a string. The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) say, "The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string." Also:

> Return value
>   The Object corresponding to the given JSON text.
>
> Exceptions
>   Throws a SyntaxError exception if the string to parse is not valid JSON.

Comment: Not reproducible as posted. `typeof flags` is "object".

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. In my real code, `data` is in fact `'"[2743,1,1,1,1,1]"'` - `data` is being set by the return value from an Ajax call to a PHP script, and PHP's `json_encode()` function seems to be adding quotes to the ends of the string (so type "string" for `JSON.parse(data)` would be correct).

Comment: I have edited your question to actually use the data you have.

Comment: @osullic `... returning a string with quotes embedded at each end. I have to strip these off first in JavaScript before JSON.parse(data)` No, these quotes should never be there in the response. Check the data you pass to `json_encode()` on your server, and fix that! *(could it be that you `json_encode()` the value twice?)* Don't attempt to patch a buggy response from the server in the frontend. Fix the response.

Comment: @Thomas Your suspicion was correct - there were other errors I had to deal with, but ultimately, the problem I was having that prompted me to ask this question was being caused by my server-side code calling `json_encode()` on an already-json-encoded array (i.e. a string) before outputting.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = '"[2743,1,1,1,1,1]"';
```

This is a string containing a string. When you parse it with

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
```

What you get is the string

```
"[2743,1,1,1,1,1]"
```

If you parse that a second time you will get your array of flags.

Try this

```
var flags = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an object and everything's OK, check the snippet:

```js
var data = '[2743,1,1,1,1,1]';
var flags = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(typeof flags);
console.log(flags);
```

Comment: You're right. Actually, what I posted above was a simplified version of my code, which in reality has `data` being set by the return of a jQuery/Ajax call. It seems PHP's `json_encode()` function (which is on the other end of the Ajax call) is returning a string with quotes embedded at each end. I have to strip these off first in JavaScript before `JSON.parse(data)` does what I want it to do.

Comment: @osullic, the problem was more complex that I thought =) Nice to hear, that you know, where is the issue